# How to load a new user control without opening a new window in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I put [this WPF application http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=164](http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=164) together

http://tanguay.info/web/index.php?pg=codeExamples&id=164

which reads an XML file of customers, allows the user to edit them and saves it back, **and it all works well**.

However, when the user clicks Save on the "manage customers" page, **I want the application to "go back" to the "show customers" page.**

The "pages" are user controls being dynamically loaded in the shell like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Reflection;
using TestDynamicForm123.View;

namespace TestDynamicForm123
{
    public partial class Shell : Window
    {
        private Dictionary<string, IBaseView> _userControls = new Dictionary<string, IBaseView>();

        public Dictionary<string, IBaseView> GetUserControls()
        {
            return _userControls;
        }

        public Shell()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            List<string> userControlKeys = new List<string>();
            userControlKeys.Add("WelcomeView");
            userControlKeys.Add("CustomersView");
            userControlKeys.Add("ManageCustomersView");
            Type type = this.GetType();
            Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;
            foreach (string userControlKey in userControlKeys)
            {
                string userControlFullName = String.Format("{0}.View.{1}", type.Namespace, userControlKey);
                IBaseView userControl = (IBaseView)assembly.CreateInstance(userControlFullName);
                _userControls.Add(userControlKey, userControl);
            }

            //set the default page
            btnWelcome.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
        }

        private void btnGeneral_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PanelMainContent.Children.Clear();
            Button button = (Button)e.OriginalSource;
            PanelMainWrapper.Header = button.Content;
            Type type = this.GetType();
            Assembly assembly = type.Assembly;

            IBaseView userControl = _userControls[button.Tag.ToString()] as IBaseView;
            userControl.SetDataContext();


            PanelMainContent.Children.Add(userControl as UserControl);
        }
    }
}
```

So when the **ManageCustomersView** is loaded and handles the click, I then try to go back to the **CustomersView** page, which works, but it opens up a new window **so every time the user edits a customer, a new window pops up afterward**.

```
private void OnSave(object sender, System.Windows.Input.ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Customer customer = e.Parameter as Customer;
    Customer.Save(customer);

    //go back to default back
    Shell shell = new Shell();
    Button btnCustomers = shell.FindName("btnCustomers") as Button;
    btnCustomers.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(Button.ClickEvent));
    shell.Show();
}
```

**How can I change the above code inside one UserControl so that its *parent* unloads the current user control and loads another one, instead of popping up another instance of the application as it does now?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new window clearly pops up because you are creating a new Shell object each time OnSave is called. You need to [get the parent Shell window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent).

```
Shell parentShell = Window.GetWindow(this) as Shell;
```

Comment: That is clearly what I was looking for, was trying to find something called "parent", excellent, thanks!