# Get the name of the parent user control WPF C#

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have access to User Control A. I want to get info on User Control C. Is there any way to do this in WPF? The structure is basically what you see. User Control D is a ribbon, C is a tab on the ribbon and B and A are contents of C. I can't seem to get access to C. I tried using the Parent property of A but it doesn't seem to give me the info on C.

[image]

Comment: What does the `Parent` property give you instead?

Comment: I think it gives the window or some other obscure element. The program is ridiculously complicated.

Comment: Are you using MVVM?  If not I would recommend using this approach.  This way you can get access to the base logic (View Models) under neath without trying to jump across controls directly.

Comment: Can you cast the Parent Window to Control C?

Comment: +1 for the beautiful illustration! :)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try using `VisualTreeHelper.GetParent` or use the recursive function [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent)

Comment: Awesome I'll try that on Monday. Thanks

Comment: This does work however it turns out this question doesn't solve my problem. Checkmark and +1 for right answer though! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Maybe you can try to cast the parent as UserControl C, like this:

```
(this.Parent as UserControlC).YourProperty
```

Answer (score -1):

use the Window.GetWindow(this) method within Loaded event handler.

```
public MainView()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainView_Loaded);
}

void MainView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window parentWindow = Window.GetWindow(this);

    ...
}
```