# how does a custom control in a usercontrol find the parent of the usercontrol in WPF?

Tags: wpf, controls, parent

I have a custom control that is used in a usercontrol, and this usercontrol is hosted in a MainUsercontrol.

now, when an event occurs in the custom control, the selected tab in the MainUsercontrol should change.

Is there a way to say something like the following??

```
this.Parent.Parent.SelectTab(1);
```

?

Comment: can you create a dependency property in your custom control and bind your SelectedIndex for your MainUsercontrol TabControl to this property?

Comment: In Xaml, you can do this using RelativeSource, example: ...="{Binding Height, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={namespace:ManUsercontrol}}". In Code-behind, imho you cannot do it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing such stuff on a parent control directly from a child is generally frowned upon.

Why don't you make this event in your child control a bubbling `RoutedEvent` to let the parent in the visual tree handle the event and action accordingly as it see's fit.

Some helpful links:

[How to: Create a Custom Routed Event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752288.aspx)

[Extensive - Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx)

Sample:

A demo showing your use case where the `MainWindow` holds a `UserControl` which holds another `UserControl` within it and the `MainWindow` handles the custom event raised by the grand child `UserControl`.

[Download Link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/e8cmzxj7zs4cd1v/WpfApplication48.rar)

Comment: In short: The routed event should use the bubble technique to propagate upward in the element tree

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answers... I found the below solution, but i'll look in to the solutions presented here above as well....

First Get the Parent Window
[WPF User Control Parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent)

Then foreach for the Usercontrol
and then Foreach again to find the Tabcontrol 
[Find all controls in WPF Window by type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/974598/find-all-controls-in-wpf-window-by-type)