# Minimize a window in WPF from page

Tags: wpf

How i can minimize window from page?

I tried to do this, but it crashes the program.

```
private void minimizeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           (this.Parent as Window).WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
        }
```

Comment: You can use the `static Window.GetWindow()` method, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent

Answer (score 0):

You can minimize the current window via Page as:

```
private void minimizeBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window.GetWindow(this).WindowState = WindowState.Minimized;
}
```