How do I get the Window that the UserControl belongs to?
Am I trying to get the window that the usercontrol belongs to?
I am trying to open a dialog box from a custom usercontrol, the current window is needed to open it. What can I do?
This is what I'm doing now, but how good is this solution?
            var window = this.GetVisualRoot();
            var result = await dialog.ShowDialog<bool>((Window)window);


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302839/wpf-user-control-parent

I used this
TopLevel.GetTopLevel(this) as Window


You can retrieve the main window by casting current application lifetime to IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime:
if (Avalonia.Application.Current.ApplicationLifetime is IClassicDesktopStyleApplicationLifetime desktop)
{
   var currentWindow = desktop.MainWindow;
   await dialog.ShowDialog<bool>(currentWindow);
}
else
{
   // handle mobile and browser platforms if applicable
}

