# mvvm observablecollection and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have a model:

```
public class Table : ViewModelBase
{
    private int _id;
    private string _north;
    private string _east;
    private string _south;
    private string _west;

    public int Id
    {
        get
        {
            return _id;
        }
        set
        {
            _id = value; OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string North
    {
        get { return _north; }
        set { _north = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public string East
    {
        get { return _east; }
        set { _east = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public string South
    {
        get { return _south; }
        set { _south = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }

    public string West
    {
        get { return _west; }
        set { _west = value; OnPropertyChanged();}
    }
}
```

Also ViewModel where tables list declared:

```
            Tables = new ObservableCollection<Table>();
```

And in XAML:

```
<ScrollViewer.Resources>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate x:Name="MyWrapPanel">
                    <toolkit:WrapPanel MinWidth="250" Width="{Binding ViewportWidth, ElementName=MyScrollViewer}" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </ScrollViewer.Resources>

            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}" ItemsPanel="{StaticResource MyWrapPanel}" Grid.RowSpan="2" Grid.Row="1">
                <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <controls:TableControl 
                            TableNumber="{Binding Id}"
                            North="{Binding North}"
                            East="{Binding East}"
                            South="{Binding South}"
                            West="{Binding West}"
                            />
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            </ItemsControl>

        </ScrollViewer>
```

But when I add elements to Tables list, there is all OK.
But

```
TableNumber="{Binding Id}"
North="{Binding North}"
East="{Binding East}"
South="{Binding South}"
West="{Binding West}"
```

are not bound indeed.

Comment: What is `ViewModelBase`? You need to specify the property name in `OnPropertyChanged();`. Is that happening in `ViewModelBase` via reflection or something?

Comment: post the code and XAML of the `TableControl`.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange that is a [feature in .Net 4.5](http://blog.develop.com/inotifypropertychanged-in-net-45utm_campaigndevelopments-April-2012utm_sourcedevelopments/)

Comment: @HighCore He didn't mention he's using .NET 4.5. These small mistakes are common for WPF beginners.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange agreed

Comment: Looks correct.  Your issue may lay elsewhere.  Make sure to turn up debug messages for databinding: http://i.stack.imgur.com/MF8i5.png Next, re-run and check the output window and see what errors are there.

Comment: Pls add the correct .Net version tag that you are using.

Comment: Its not necessary be 4.5 You can create your own attribute:          [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
    public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute { }
An it will be working nice ad neat even I Silverlight

Answer (score 0):

In the `Xaml` file of your user control named `TableControl`, add `DataContext={Binding}` *in the root element* and I think it should then work (if it's not present).

It could also be not working if you have `DataContext` set *inside* the code behind of your user control's (e.g.`TableControl.xaml.cs`) file to something like `this.DataContext = this;` which makes user control not use the DataContext of `Tables` collection.

You can use [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/299247/885920) to check what exactly is in the DataContext of your user control `TableControl`.

**Edit:**

Try below also, because as per your comment, DataContext for `TableControl` is conflicting:

```
<DataTemplate>
    <controls:TableControl DataContext="{Binding}" 
        TableNumber="{Binding Id}"
        North="{Binding North}"
        East="{Binding East}"
        South="{Binding South}"
        West="{Binding West}"
        />
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: The code had DataContext = this; and some DependenceProperites. Nothing interesting really at all :)

Comment: @alerya updated answer to add XAML as per your comment. Check if it works otherwise you would need to find some other alternative.