# Access bound variables that come from parent user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, datacontext

I have a parent user control which holds another one called `TrainDetailsControl`. The data context of the parent user control is set to a ViewModel class (see below).

```
<UserControl>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Trains}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTrain}"
                 DisplayMemberPath="Name"/>
        <local:TrainDetailsControl Grid.Column="1" DataContext="{Binding SelectedTrain}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

What I do is "pass" the selected train in the list box to the `TrainDetailsControls`. Inside that user control I show the details of the selected train object.

```
<UserControl>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Details}"/>
    </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

This is the ViewModel with the shared variables (this is not the complete code, just to give you an idea).

```
public class TrainViewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    public ObservableCollection<Train> Trains { get; }
        = new ObservableCollection<Train>();

    private Train selectedTrain;
    public Train SelectedTrain
    {
        get { return selectedTrain; }
        set { SetValue(ref selectedTrain, value); }
    }
}
```

This works well, as when I select a train item from the list box, its details are shown correctly in the other user control. But I'm wondering if it is possible to access Name and Details variables from code-behind in `TrainDetailsControl`. Would the data context of this last user control be the same as the data context of its parent user control (i.e. the view model class)?

Comment: No, the DataContext is whatever the SelectedTrain property returns.

Comment: @mm8 And can I access it from code-behind (I mean, from the child user control)?

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But I'm wondering if it is possible to access Name and Details variables from code-behind in TrainDetailsControl

Sure. Just cast the `DataContext` to `Train` once the view has been loaded:

```
public partial class TrainDetailsControl : UserControl
{
    public TrainDetailsControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Loaded += (s, e) =>
        {
            Train selectedTrain = DataContext as Train;
            if (selectedTrain != null)
            {
                //...
            }
        };
    }
}
```

> Would the data context of this last user control be the same as the data context of its parent user control (i.e. the view model class)?

No, it would the object that `SelectedTrain` returns since you have bound the `DataContext` property to this source property. If you don't explicitly set the DataContext property, the DataContext would be inherited from the parent `UserControl` though.

Comment: Thanks for the precise answer. I understand your code, but do you know any reason why am I getting `null` DataContext?

Comment: I think I have it. DataContext is `null` until I select something from the list box. [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/296503/wpf-user-controls-datacontext-is-null) gave me a hint (just in case this helps someone).